# Execute callback in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, parallel-processing

I know Node.js is single threaded and uses asynchronous operations for I/O.

> whenever Node.js is not executing code, the runtime checks for events
>   (more accurately it uses platform-native API’s which allow it to be
>   activated when events occur). Whenever control is passed to the
>   Node.js runtime, another event can be processed. The event could be
>   from an HTTP client connection, or perhaps from a file read.

How many callbacks can execute at the same time in Node?

Comment: Are you looking for some "absolute" limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your own code executes in a single thread, so only one callback is actively running at a time, and it will continue to run until it calls an async function or completes.

Answer (score 1):

Node runs on an event loop, which you can think of as a queue of callbacks to be processed each tick of the event loop. Therefore, callbacks are executed one by one since the loop is on a single thread, which is what makes functions such as `process.nextTick()` available.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one callback firing at the same time.